# Vue3 - TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'basketCount'

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-component

I have a problem. I'm using **props** to **update** my **basketCount** but I have a problem:

[image: This is my error when I try to update my basketCount variable]

How can I update my **basketCount** ? Can you give me some advice please ?

These are my codes:

> Home.vue

```
<template>
            ...

            <ProductList :basketCount="basketCount" :itemList="itemList" />

            ...


</template>



<script>

export default {

  data() {
     return {
        ...
        basketCount:0
        ...
        
    }
},


created() {

    
        this.$axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/baskets?userId=${this.getUser.id}`).then(get_response => {

            this.basketCount = get_response.data.length || 0

        })

    
     

    ...

},
}
```

I'm skipping **ProductList** part and I'm showing you my **addToBasket** function in **ProductListItem.vue**

```
addToBasket(item) {



        this.$axios.post("http://localhost:3000/baskets", item).then(basket_response => 
        {

            console.log(basket_response);
            this.basketCount++

        });
    }
```

Comment: You can't mutate props, that's what the error is about.

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for comment, so how can I update ?

Comment: With events. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for help. I solved this problem with **provide/inject**

Comment: provide/inject is an overkill for direct parent-child link. v-model is universally used for that